# htaccess redirect replacing %20 with hyphen only for file names

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to replace %20 white spaces in File names of requested URLs.

I'm using this Regex: `^(.*)\s(.*)$` which replace all of white spaces in the Url. I'm unable to make it working only for file names.

```
http://example.com/subfolder/One More Sub Folder/Onother Sub Folder/File%20test%20example.jpg
```

I'm under wordpress and I need a RewriteCondition and RewriteRule to make this:

```
http://example.com/wordpress/subfolder/One More Sub Folder/Onother Sub Folder/File-test-example.jpg
```

I also need same replace for htm requests, but I need to remove html extension from file names, too.

So now I have these Rules that are working for html:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.htm|\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.htm|\.html)$ http://www.example.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and these for redirecting jpg:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.jpg)$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/$1 [R=301,L]
```

At the beginning of the htaccess file I have the lowercase transformation needed for wp slug to work:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are existent files, you can use the following rule to replace %20 with - :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /$1-$2 [NC,L,R]
```

The rule is applied only for existent files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `RewriteRule ^(.*)(%20)(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,NE,L]`?